# how to user multiple pivot function in a sql statement?

Tags: sql

Input---

```
Order Status    Mode    Recipient
Confirmed       Mail    Customer
Confirmed        Fax    Customer
Confirmed      Mobile   Customer
Confirmed       Mail    Vendor
Confirmed        Fax    Vendor
```

Output ---

```
  Event   Mail  Fax Mobile
Confirmed   3    3   3
Received    3    3   3
Dispatched  3    3   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question not clear. Based on my understanding you want pivot table from sql.

```
SELECT* FROM TableTest

SELECT *  FROM
(SELECT  OrderStatus, Mode FROM TableTest) AS P
PIVOT (Count(Mode) FOR Mode IN (Mail, Mobile, Fax )) AS pv

SELECT *  FROM
(SELECT  Recipient, Mode FROM TableTest ) AS P
PIVOT ( Count(Mode) FOR Mode IN (Mail, Mobile, Fax )) AS pv
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Siva. But i am looking for the result in a single set. Is their any way this can be done.

Comment: I am very difficult to understand single set. Please give me you output syntax.